# Reviewing Data Structures and Algorithms

Tags: data-structures

I was wondering if anyone had knew of a website that provides a great review of data structures and algorithms. I would like it to specifically geared towards interview questions with regards to data structures and algorithms. Would implementation of all of these data structures be something good to review?

Thanks!

Comment: What's your goal? If you need to know the material for an interview, or it is necessary for your coding, then it's definitely good to review.

Comment: `careercup.com` and `geeksforgeeks.com` have lots of interview questions

Answer (score 6):

This [page](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) is a good starting point:

> This webpage covers the space and time Big-O complexities of common algorithms used in Computer Science.  When preparing for technical interviews in the past, I found myself spending hours crawling the internet putting together the best, average, and worst case complexities for search and sorting algorithms so that I wouldn't be stumped when asked about them.  Over the last few years, I've interviewed at several Silicon Valley startups, and also some bigger companies, like Yahoo, eBay, LinkedIn, and Google, and each time that I prepared for an interview, I thought to msyelf "Why oh why hasn't someone created a nice Big-O cheat sheet?".  So, to save all of you fine folks a ton of time, I went ahead and created one.